# Get currently opened browser URL

Tags: java, android, android-activity

At first I wanted to get text from the currently opened activity, but that wasn't possible because of security reasons. Now I want to get the currently opened browser URL. So I could use the user's history, but this wouldn't work if the user switches between tabs.

I will initiate this action by using a background service that shows a button above the browser, if you click that button you'll get the current browser URL.

Comment: "I want to check the activity name of the currently opened third party app" -- this is no longer strictly possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Plus, on Android 7.0+ with multi-window, there can be more than one "currently opened third party app". Also, bear in mind that "get the text of the currently opened activity" is only possible using an accessibility service, so you will want to [consider Google's recent policy changes regarding those](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/20/accessibilityservice-bans.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Fair enough, is there a way though to get the browser's current URL if a browser is open? I know I can look into the Chrome history of the user, but that could give confusing results if it doesn't match the current page when I switch between tabs.

Comment: "is there a way though to get the browser's current URL if a browser is open?" -- there are dozens, if not hundreds, of Web browser apps for Android. None have to offer an API to get the current URL. There might be multiple current URLs. Via an accessibility service, you are out of luck, as the URL may not be in a visible widget. That's on top of all the problems I outlined earlier.

Comment: @CommonsWare Makes sense, then I'll just have to do it with the Chrome history and make this clear to my users somehow. I expect most of my users to use Chrome, so I guess it's not a huge deal. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!